# running background CLI installed from NPM module in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I seem to be missing some fundamental knowledge about Docker. I have a `docker-compose.yml` and I want to add there another service that basically installs a module from NPM and runs a few commands ending with one that serves UI application.

When I choose `node` as base image, it starts its REPL and I cannot install a module from it. Looking at the Dockerfile of the `node` image, there is a whole bunch of stuff. Am I really supposed to copy all that and start `bash` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own docker image where the packages you want are already installed. You create a Dockerfile use FROM: node copy your package.json and your script sources and run npm install I'm the Dockerfile. You should overwrite the command to run your script. Build this image. Now use this image.

Comment: Wait, so when I create Dockerfile `FROM node`, build an image from it, then the `RUN` command from the original is ignored? That would be nice, I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: RUN is part of the image and you typically want that. You can override the CMD or ENTRYPOINT of the starting image. Vast majority of images that start FROM: node are express projects that have a package.json entry to start the server and CMD starts the server

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed a fundamental part I somehow missed in docs.